# JSP on click working in fireox. Not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

Hi I have a click event associated with  which has JSP parameters `<a href="javascript:void()"><div class="icn_Deactivate" title="Deactivate" onclick="deactivate(<%=module.getAgreementType() %>,'N')">`

```
<a href="#abc" onclick='getHTML(<%=module.getAgreementType()%>,"html")'><%=templates.getLegalDocTmplFileName() %></a>
```

but in the html page it is coming up like this[image: here]. Please help!

Comment: What is the value of `module.getAgreementType()`? What is the value of `templates.getLegalDocTmplFileName()`? What does getHTML() do? If getHTML() returns HTML, why do you fill `onclick` with HTML?